# Enviar objeto do AngularJs para POST da WebAPI C#

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um formulário, que estou tentando salvar as informações no banco de dados SQL Server.

```
<html ng-app="Crm">
<body ng-controller="CrmCtrl">
<form name="novoCrmForm">
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group text-left col-md-8">
        <label for="Nome">Nome <i class="danger">*</i></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.NOME_FANTASIA" ng-required="true" name="NOME_FANTASIA" placeholder="Nome">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left col-md-4">
        <label for="cpf">CPF</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.CNPJ_CPF" name="CNPJ_CPF" placeholder="CPF">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
        <label for="Telefone">Telefone</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.TELEFONE_01" name="TELEFONE_01" placeholder="Telefone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-left col-md-6">
        <label for="Celular">Celular <i class="danger">*</i></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.CELULAR" ng-required="true" name="CELULAR" placeholder="Celular">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group text-left col-md-12">
        <label for="Email">Email <i class="danger">*</i></label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="empresaParticipante.EMAIL" ng-required="true" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Este formulário esta enviando o objeto para uma `function` em AngularJs pelo button abaixo:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="adicionarRegistro(empresaParticipante)" ng-disabled="novoCrmForm.$invalid">Salvar</button>
```

No AngularJs, quando chega na `function adicionarRegistro`, eu coloquei um `console.logo(empresaParticipante)` para verificar se o objeto realmente esta chegando nesta function.

```
var crmApp = angular.module("Crm", []);
crmApp.controller("CrmCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.adicionarRegistro = function (empresaParticipante) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:50183/api/crm/salvar", JSON.stringify(empresaParticipante)).success(function (data) {
        delete $scope.empresaParticipante;
        $scope.novoCrmForm.$setPristine();
        console.log(empresaParticipante);
        carregarRegistros();
    });
};

carregarRegistros();
});
```

Até aqui, após verificar o console, consigo ver o objeto preenchido.

o objeto:

```
{"NOME_FANTASIA":"bruno","CNPJ_CPF":"111.222.333-44","TELEFONE_01":"(000) 00000-0011","CELULAR":"(000) 00000-0022","EMAIL":"teste@teste.com.br"}
```

no mesmo console, em Resposta, apresenta a seguinte mensagem:

```
{"mensagem":"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities
 may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId
=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.","objeto":null
,"lista":[],"status":false}
```

Esta é a classe:

```
public partial class EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES
{
public int ID { get; set; }

[StringLength(150)]
public string NOME_FANTASIA { get; set; }

[StringLength(20)]
public string CNPJ_CPF { get; set; }

[StringLength(20)]
public string TELEFONE_01 { get; set; }

[StringLength(20)]
public string CELULAR { get; set; }

[StringLength(100)]
public string EMAIL { get; set; }

[Column(TypeName = "date")]
public DateTime? DATA_CADASTRO { get; set; }
}
```

Este objeto deveria chegar preenchido neste método da API.

```
[Route("salvar")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage post([FromBody] EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES empresaParticipante)
    {
        IEmpresas_ParticipantesBO Empresas_ParticipantesBO = new Empresas_ParticipantesBO();
        Retorno retorno = new Retorno();

        try
        {
            //salvar
            retorno = Empresas_ParticipantesBO.salvar(empresaParticipante);
```

**Como fazer este objeto chegar preenchido na API e qual o motivo desta mensagem apresentada na Resposta?**

Comment: Tem como postar a estrutura (propriedades) da classe `EMPRESAS_PARTICIPANTES`?

Comment: classe postada!

Comment: O objeto `empresaParticipante` está nulo ou ele vem correto?

Comment: esta chegando na API null.

Comment: Tira aquele `JSON.stringify` na hora de enviar o objeto. Você não precisa mandar uma string, precisa mandar um objeto mesmo.

Comment: Este erro é do Entity Framework. Como está o código que insere o registro em banco?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Ele tá recebendo um objeto nulo, provavelmente o problema tem a ver com isso.

Answer (score 0):

Uma possibilidade de o objeto `empresaParticipante` vir null é devido ao header da chamada POST.

O Content-Type deve ser do tipo `application/json`

Para incluir o Content-Type à chamada:

```
$scope.adicionarRegistro = function (empresaParticipante) {
    var config; 

    config = {
        url : '/api/crm/salvar',
        method : 'POST',
        responseType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify(dataObj),
        headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }
    };


    $http(config).success(function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(empresaParticipante));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response);       

        $scope.empresaParticipante = {};
        $scope.novoCrmForm.$setPristine();
        carregarRegistros();
    })
    .error(function(error){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error);
    });
};
```